# Сделать функцию для массива

Tags: массивы, c++, c++11

Как сделать функции для этого массива на
Ввод массива
Вывод массива
Ввод размера
и ещё функцию на нахождение суммы элементов или максимума.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
float A[30],max,X,sum=0;
int Nmax, n,i;
bool flag = false;
while(1)
{
printf("n=");
scanf("%d",&n);
if (n>0 && n<=30) {
break;
}
printf("0<n<30");>);
}
{
printf("X ");
scanf("%f",&X);
max = A[0];
Nmax = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
if (fabs(A-X)<=5) {
sum+=A;
}
else {
flag = true;
if (A > max) {
max = A;
Nmax = i;
}
}

}
```

Помогите

```
}
printf("summa = %7.2f\n",sum);
if (flag) {
printf("maxA=%7.2f Nmax=%4.1d", max , Nmax);
}
else {
printf("Vse elementy po modulu razlichni ne bolee chem na 5 ot x");
}
getch();
}
```

Comment: > c++11  
> [printf]http://i.imgur.com/XGrDIhC.jpg

Comment: @VladD боюсь, ТС не поймет вашего сарказма

Comment: даже не знаю что тут забавнее **С++** или **11**

Answer (score 1):

```
int n;

int a[30];
void ArrInput()
{
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
      cin >> a[i];
}
void ArrOutput()
{
    for(int i=0; i<30; i++)
      cout << a[i];
}
void SetSize()
{
    cin >> n;
}

void Sum(){
    int s=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    s+=a[i];
     cout << s;

}

void Max()
{
    int m = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < 30; i++)
    {
        if (a[i]> m)
            m = a[i];
    }
    cout << m;
}

 код скорее всего не скомпилируется, так как на скорую руку, но в нем есть ответы на ваши вопросы, если поискать)
```